# Expression for flux for diffusion equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Sorry for posting such a trivial question. I've been learning about numerically solving PDEs with no formal background in it and read the following example:

> Steady-state diffusion equation in 1-dimension:
>
> $\nabla \cdot (D\nabla\phi)=0$,
>
> has boundary conditions $\phi=0$ at $x=0$ and $D \frac{\partial
>  \phi}{\partial x}=1$ at $x=L$.
>
> The boundary conditions are therefore a fixed value of 0 to the left and **a fixed flux of 1** to the right.

I found the **flux part** confusing since I understood flux to be defined as $\vec{n}\cdot \nabla \phi$, which seems different from the above expression: $D \frac{\partial
 \phi}{\partial x}$, or simply, $D \nabla \phi$. What rudimentary concept am I not getting here?

Comment: It looks like your problem is in one dimension (based on your boundary conditions)? In this case $\vec{n}(L)=1$ and $\vec{n}(0)=-1$ (i.e., the outward normal points to the right $x=L$ and to the left at $x=0$). In one dimension $\nabla \phi = \frac{d\phi}{dx}$.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks! But, based on that, shouldn't the flux at $L$ be $1 \cdot \frac{d\phi}{dx}$? Why should diffusion coefficient $D$ be part of it at all, as the problem implied?

Comment: No, the flux through the boundary is $-D\nabla \phi \cdot \vec{n}$, where $D$ is the thermal conductivity or diffusion coefficient. This is Fourier's law of heat conduction.